# sqlldr hangs, doesn't appear to recognize control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

My old machine had some hardware trouble and now I'm trying to get everything running on a new box. Oracle is installed and my database is loaded. I have a process that automatically creates batch files, control files, and data files. After the files are created it runs the batch file. It's worked very well. But on this new machine is just hangs.

A similar question (with no answers) is this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374488/sqlldr-doent-execute-when-invoked-from-command-prompt.

My bat file contains something like this:

```
sqlldr user/password control='C:\Users\Public\Documents\sqlldr\test.ctl'
```

Control file looks something like this:

```
load data infile 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\sqlldr\test.csv' replace into table test_table fields terminated by "|" TRAILING NULLCOLS (field1 char(12), field2 char(16))
```

My test.csv file has one record in it. It will typically have tens of thousands. The only thing I get in the console, whether I run the bat file or type the sqlldr command in directly, is:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Sep 24 11:08:14 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
```

If I pass in an invalid ctl file name it gives me an error. Or if I use an invalid user/pass it won't continue. The strange part is that if I change the name of the csv file to something invalid it still just sits there and I don't get an error.

Any ideas? Could it have anything to do with my path variables? I wouldn't think so since it seems to find sqlldr, but at this point I'm not sure.

Comment: can you post your table structure and your input file content as well?

Comment: Here is something interesting. My normal table is kind of a monster and not one I can share, so I setup a simple table named "test_table" with the two columns above, field1 and field2. And it worked. Could it be a permissions issue? I created my normal tables from a exp dump. My test table I created in SQL Plus while signed in as my primary user. I'm more confused now.

Comment: It might be because, the loading is in progress. Did you check for any locks over the table?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do I check for locks? I don't think it's loading because I only put one record in the csv file as a test.

Comment: try this query please.. `select substr(c.owner,1,10) owner,substr(c.object_name,1,18) object_name,substr(c.object_type,1,15) type,b.sid,b.serial#,b.status,substr(b.osuser,1,10) osuser,substr(b.machine,1,17) machine
 from v$locked_object a,v$session b,dba_objects c 
 where 
 b.sid = a.session_id and 
 a.object_id = c.object_id;`

Comment: No rows selected. I did drop and recreate one of my tables and now the import works correctly for that table. Has to be a permissions issue of some sort. Just wish it gave me an error message.